# Is there a way to preview a document stored on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some files stored in a directory on the server application. Actually, this folder is inside my app's folder.

Is there a way to preview these files (most of then xls, docs and pdfs) using a component or a custom control ?

Comment: Does preview mean something like in gmail?

Comment: I don't know. I don't use Gmail. How does it like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use [Google Docs Viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer).

Basically you call the viewer URL and pass the full qualified public URL to a document on your server and the Google Docs Viewer will render your document to HTML.

The [documentation states](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=de&answer=1738646) that they support the following document types:

- Microsoft Word (.DOC and .DOCX)
- Microsoft Excel (.XLS and .XLSX)
- Microsoft PowerPoint (.PPT and .PPTX)
- Adobe Portable Document Format (.PDF)
- Apple Pages (.PAGES)
- Adobe Illustrator (.AI)
- Adobe Photoshop (.PSD)
- Tagged Image File Format (.TIFF)
- Autodesk AutoCad (.DXF)
- Scalable Vector Graphics (.SVG)
- PostScript (.EPS, .PS)
- TrueType (.TTF)
- XML Paper Specification (.XPS)
- Archive file types (.ZIP and .RAR)

Comment: But can I integrate my webapp with Google Docs Viewer? Or my webapp should upload all files to GoogleDocs?

Comment: @LukinhaRS You don't need to upload to Google. Just pass the full URL to your files as a parameter.

Comment: They have some scary TOS though.. Anything you submit/display through/on that service will be yours.. And theirs. (From what I understood)